# CodeIgniter abre muitas conexões com o Banco de dados

Tags: php, banco-de-dados, codeigniter, conexão

Tenho uma aplicação no cliente e eles estão reclamando que ela está abrindo muitas conexões com o banco de dados, fazendo cair o servidor.

Procurei na internet e não achei algo relacionado.

Gostaria de saber se o CodeIgniter fecha automaticmente a conexão com o banco quando ela é realizada ou se tem algo para fechar.

Sou novo com CodeIgniter e a aplicação já estava feita quando entrei aqui. Ela está usando `Active Record` para fazer as *queries*.

Comment: Obteve alguma resposta LigDark???

Answer (score 1):

Em `application/config/database.php`, verifique se a configuração `$db['default']['pconnect'] = TRUE;` coloque `FALSE`, porque, com `TRUE` a conexão fica persistente.

```
$active_group = 'default';
$active_record = TRUE;

$db['default']['hostname'] = 'localhost';
$db['default']['username'] = 'root';
$db['default']['password'] = 'senha';
$db['default']['database'] = 'testdb';
$db['default']['dbdriver'] = 'mysql';
$db['default']['dbprefix'] = '';
$db['default']['pconnect'] = FALSE; // Coloque FALSE
$db['default']['db_debug'] = TRUE;
$db['default']['cache_on'] = FALSE;
$db['default']['cachedir'] = '';
$db['default']['char_set'] = 'utf8';
$db['default']['dbcollat'] = 'utf8_general_ci';
$db['default']['swap_pre'] = '';
$db['default']['autoinit'] = TRUE;
$db['default']['stricton'] = FALSE;
```

***Obs:*** *É a única configuração que tem esse perfil de deixar a conexão aberta*

Comment: Mandei a solução para o cliente , e não obtive retorno ainda, mas acho que deu certo.
Valeu mano.

Comment: Alguma Noticia @LigDark

Comment: Cara, acho que funcionou , não tive um retorno negativo do cliente... obg :)

Answer (score -3):

No caso da conexão acima desabilita o db_debug ($db['default'][''] = FALSE);
As conexões com o banco vão ter um desempenho melhor.